# Finding out the size of an Asset file in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, file, assets

Is there a way to find out the size of an asset file in kotlin android? I am wanting to know the size of a group of files so as I can then confirm the device has enough free space to copy the files to internal memory.

I have searched on Google and Stack Overflow, however I have not found anything that was able to assist

UPDATE:

I have figured out two possible solutions:

1. `context.assets.open("FILE").available()`
2. `context.assets.open("FILE").readBytes().size`

Which is a better way and more efficient and accurate? I have read that `available()` is not completely accurate. Is this true? [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16567701/15197405). If this is truly the case, does that mean reading the bytes from the inputstream (as shown in case number 2) is the best way?

Comment: Well you are the one who should tell us if available() was not equal to size() for your files. Simple test.

Comment: But why are you afraid that a device would not have enough space for a few files? And why would you even copy them?

Comment: There may be some instances where someone's device does not have enough space left, and I want to provide a fail safe. I wish to copy them over, so that the user can use quickly efficiently and easily. If you have a 100mb text file (extreme, but possible) and the app needs to unpack the asset every time before use, it is extremely inefficient and slow.

Comment: As you did not tell what the user wants to do with the text file we still dont know why you first wanna make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `openFd`

```
val fileSize = context.assets.openFd("FILE").length
```